# D-link DIR-615: slow speeds

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a D-link DIR-615 as a router. For a year now, I have been observing a long pause at the beginning of loading my web page. When I go to speedtest.net , my download speed is 10 Mbps. I think the problem is in DNS, but the provider does not let me choose another DNS - the Internet disappears immediately. What can be done in this case?

Comment: That is an ancient and vulnerable router, time to upgrade it.

Comment: Ask ISP to change the WAN cable. Put a new one. It's possible that it's damaged somewhere along the length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with flashing to DD-wrt. Probably, the factory firmware has a speed limit that forces you to buy a router of a newer model.

Answer (score 3):

The D-Link DIR-615 is 2.4GHz only, 2x2, 802.11n (Wi-Fi 4, which came out in 2007) device. It can get a 300Mbps PHY rate (the raw signaling before subtracting protocol overhead of 30-40%), but only if it uses 40MHz-wide channels, which is hard to do in the crowded 2.4GHz band. Modern smartphones, tablets, and laptops that support both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth will signal "40MHz intolerance" to the Wi-Fi network, which forces the Wi-Fi network to use 20MHz-wide channels to leave room for Bluetooth.

This means that even if your 2x2 MIMO client device is well within ideal range of it, and it's on a clean channel (again, hard to find in 2.4GHz), your maximum PHY rate will probably be 144Mbps, which after overhead comes out to maybe 90Mbps, which is about 11 MebiBytes/sec.

If your client device isn't MIMO (e.g. it's "SISO" or 1x1), then you'd only see about 40Mbps (5 MiB/sec), and only in ideal signal/noise conditions.

Even with extremely generous assumptions, you could never have seen even as much as 30Mbps out of that device.

You got your money's worth from that router and it's time to modernize. Heck, it's a decade past time to modernize. You can get a decent Wi-Fi 6 router for $70 and expect a decent Wi-Fi 6 client to get >600Mbps from it (if the speed of residential broadband line you're paying for from your ISP is at least that fast).

Answer (score 0):

The speeds would suggest something is only connecting at 10Base-T rather than 100. I can't remember whether the DIR-615 had yellow/green LED status lamps on the connectors.
Check that all lights on it are green not yellow.

All really do remember about the unit is it wasn't very good when it was new; it was only draft-spec 802.11n, it had a nasty habit of forcing browser elections & stealing the master browser, which it was incapable of fulfilling... & now it could be almost 20 years old, depending on revision.

Comment: All light are green. The strangest thing is that this problem appeared a year ago. Everything worked well before that

Comment: consumer-grade internet access routers don't generally last that long (3-5 years on average IME) and what you describe is not uncommon for one on its last legs. Most of the time, you can set your devices to use a DNS server you specify, even if the ISP provided equipment is using DHCP to push one of their addresses to your devices. I'd look into DNS benchmarking to test whether your issue is DNS resolution latency.

Comment: Peter - are these the front lights or does it have individual light on every socket at the back? [I can't remember if it does & the manufacturers pictures are not clear enough for me to decide] I'm not sure the front lights are a good indicator for this.

Comment: @Tetsujin, look at [this](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/electronics/d-link/dlink-DIR-615-front-lg.jpg)